# making run-time-complexity shorter (c++)

Tags: c++, runtime

The remove_dup function has a run-time complexity of O(n^2) since there are two nested repetitive loops inside. My task is to get the same results with O(n).
I don't really have a clue how that could look like.

```
 int add_without_dup (char x, vector<char>& r)
 {// pre-condition:
   assert (true) ;
 //  post-condition: x is added to the end of r if it is not yet present in r
//                  the result is the number of comparisons performed in this function
int i = 0 ;
while ( i < size(r) && r[i] != x )
    i++ ;
if ( i == size(r))
    r.push_back (x) ;
return i ;
}


int remove_dup (vector<char>& source, vector<char>& dest)

{// pre-condition:
assert (size (dest) == 0) ;
//  post-condition: dest is a copy of source without duplicate elements
//                  the result is the number of comparisons performed in this function
int nr_of_comparisons = 0 ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < size (source) ; i++)
    nr_of_comparisons += add_without_dup (source[i], dest) ;
return nr_of_comparisons ;
}
```

Comment: If possible, start by sorting the contents. Better still, just look up `std::set`.

Comment: will have a look at that, thanks.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'm not sure how you would arrive at an O(n) algorithm if you start sorting the sequence. That said, I don't quite see an O(n) algorithm for removing duplicates.

Comment: @Dietmar With an unordered_set you could get average time to O(N). Or there's Sorin's nice hack below.

Answer (score 1):

Because your char can only have 256 possible values, you can keep an `bool array[256]`. When you insert something in you set the value to true. When you want to check if it is in you check if the value is set to true or not.

The complexity is `O(N + S)` where S is the number of possible values you want to have in your vector.Usually, for char, `N >> S`, so S will not matter.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much! Cannot give you an up sadwise though :(